# My image is not flipping while it should (processing)

Tags: image, processing

Here's my code:

```
  } 
if(grievous.speed.x > 0){
  rechts = true;
 } else if(grievous.speed.x < 0){
   rechts = false;
 }
pushMatrix();
translate(grievous.pos.x, grievous.pos.y);
if(rechts == false){
scale(-1,1);
}
```

popMatrix();
}

Ive got Boolean rechts; on top. I want for the image to flip horizontally.
If grievous speed = 0 he should be standing still

Comment: What should happen if `grievous.speed.x == 0`?

Comment: What are you scaling exactly? I can see a `popMatrix` but no drawing. Scale goes _before_ what you're scaling. As in `scale(x, y); rect(x, y, w, h);`.

Comment: To make it easier for others to help you should post a minimal working example, which others can run.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example